# (Generic Class).this.revalidate(); on Mac

Tags: java, macos, swing

I'm using a 2010 Mac with 1.6.0_37 Java, using DrJava to compile. The revalidate method does not compile, and I receive the following error:

```
2 errors found:
File: /Users/#########/compsci/Final/ConnectFourFrame.java  [line: 123]
Error: /Users/#########/compsci/Final/ConnectFourFrame.java:123: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method revalidate()
location: class ConnectFourFrame
```

This is the method giving rise to the error:

```
try 
{ 
  //display in window 
  updateTitleBar(); 
  ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(currentFile)); 
  colorGrid = (Color[][]) ois.readObject(); 
  makeGrid(); 
  for(int k = 0; k < 6; k++) 
  { 
    for(int l = 0; l < 7; l++) 
    { 
      if (colorGrid[k][l]==null) 
      { 
        grid[k][l] = new BlankTile(new Point(k, l)); 
      } 
      else if (colorGrid[k][l].equals(Color.red)) 
      { 
        grid[k][l] = new RedTile(new Point(k, l)); 
      } 
      else if (colorGrid[k][l].equals(Color.black)) 
      { 
        grid[k][l] = new BlackTile(new Point(k, l)); 
      }                              
    } 
  }                        
  putNewGrid(); 
  String currentColor = (String) ois.readObject(); 
  ois.close(); 
  ConnectFourFrame.this.repaint(); 
  ConnectFourFrame.this.revalidate();  //This is the offending line
  gp.revalidate(); 
  gp.repaint(); 
}
```

And the outer class is ConnectFourFrame (extends JFrame and implements Runnable)

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: And this compiles on Windows and runs, but not on the Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Component.revalidate()` is new in Java 7.  Presumably you're using 7 on Windows as opposed to 6 on Mac.

If you need your code to work on Java 6 then you'll have to do things differently.  The [JavaDoc for Component.revalidate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#revalidate%28%29) says

> This is a convenience method supposed to help application developers avoid looking for validate roots manually. Basically, it's equivalent to first calling the `invalidate()` method on this component, and then calling the `validate()` method on the nearest validate root.

Since a `JFrame` is itself a validate root, you should just be able to replace the `revalidate` call with `invalidate()` followed by `validate()`.

Comment: `JComponent#revalidate` exists on JDK1.6 and since the class extends from `JFrame` it should compile just fine

Comment: @Robin JFrame doesn't extend JComponent.

Comment: Whoops. You are right. So used at seeing the "J" prefix meaning that it extends `JComponent` ...

Comment: @Robin I suspect the designers of swing would have liked it to be able to, but since Java doesn't do multiple inheritance and `JFrame` has to be a kind of `Window` they didn't have that option...

Answer (score 1):

1. never to manage with GUI status inside `try - catch - finally blo`ck (valid for all progr. languages)
2. in this form (you code posted here) any exception breaking refresh of Swing GUI
3. `ois.close();` should be moved to the `finally block`,
4. your issue is switch line order for `JFrame` and remove `(re)` from `revalidate` e.g. `ConnectFourFrame.this.validate(); and then ConnectFourFrame.this.repaint();`
5. no reason to use `invalidate` for `Java versions > Java5`, this method is implemented in all `LayoutManagers API` and correctly
6. in `Java7` was added `revalidate() for JFrame` in the API, use `validate()` for minor Java versions